# Django: Overriding ModelAdminForm's field attributes

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I am trying to override a ModelAdmin's form field as below:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(*args, **kwargs)
        form.fields['password'].help_text = "..."
        return form
```

I am getting an Attribute error: "type object 'FailedLoginForm' has no attribute 'fields'".

Isn't ModelAdmin.get_form() returning a regular Django form object. How come it doesn't have fields?

Comment: Do you have a simple typo: form.fields.['password'].help_text = "..."
 to form.fields['password'].help_text = "..."

Comment: sorry, the typo was in the question only, not in the code. otherwise i would get a syntax error instead of the attribute error. thanks.

Comment: Ok. When I inspect: type(self.form) I get: <class 'django.forms.models.ModelFormMetaclass'> and am not able to access the fields property either. Might not be possible to access fields from this proxy object.

Comment: it seems so. this is quiet inconsistent with the general extensibility. thanks.

Comment: There are several places in Django that don't return the type of objects we expect. It's probably easiest to just make a separate form class that this ModelAdmin uses that does the override of the label instead of trying to override the label in the ModelAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you simply override the form that you want.

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):   
    # we want to use the email as the username
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # let's require these fields
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['last_name'].required = True
        # let's not require these
        self.fields['username'].required = False
        self.fields['password1'].required = False
        self.fields['password2'].required = False
```

From there you can do pretty much anything you want.

Comment: yes, that's how i did it in the end. but i suppose your example form class should extend from `Form` or `ModelForm`.